# Visual Studio suddenly cannot compile any C++ projects, MSB6006 CL.exe exited with code -524284580

Tags: visual-studio, cl

Have been using VS for many years on C++ and C# projects. When attempting a small modification to a C++ project it would no longer build. I have both VS2019 and 2022 professional installed, valid license.

First I thought it was related to my code. But soon found out that all C++ projects failed in both versions of VS.

Tried to create a simple one line hello world program; same result.

Upgraded VS2022 to latest version, no change.

Verbose error log does not give many clues, compiler fails before it even start on any of my own files. OS is Windows 11 Pro.

Error is:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -524284580.   Hello World C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets    741

Comment: What *else* have been changed on your system between it worked and it not working? These things don't just happen out of thin air, there's always something that can be pointed at as the fault. Have you installed anything else? Done some major updates? Removed files or uninstalled things that maybe should have been left in peace?

Comment: Obviously something else has caused it, I have installed a few tools and utility programs that may have affected it. I seem to remember there was a program that installed a quite old version of DotNET, not sure if it was v 3.5 or so. Have not found anything else stopped working on my computer. VS works perfectly for C# project but not for C++. Maybe I should try to re-install VS 2022? But I'm a bit puzzled since VS 2019 also got affected. I was also hoping that someone could explain the error code -524284580 (0xE0C00D5C). Cannot find it in any of the windows headers or on general google search

Comment: Uninstalled both VS2019 and 2022, re-installed VS 2022 but still get the same error message. This is just strange.

Comment: Still have same issue. Was planning to install Visual Studio on a virtual machine just to be able to compile the C++ application. Trying to start a clean Win 11 image (or any other image) in Oracle Virtual box gives MachineWrap error with exactly the same error code as from CL.exe. I guess this cannot be a coinsidence? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I could run cl.exe successfully just after rebooting the computer, but after a minute or so it started to exit with error like before.

This lead me to thinking it was blocked by some other task that was not started until after logon.

My company uses Cylance Protect for blocking malware, and it was this application that blocked cl.exe and also VirtualBoxVM.exe that reported same error code  -524284580 (0xE0C00D5C). I have now asked IT to safelist these two apps, and I'm pretty sure it will solve it.

Comment: Yes, cl.exe, link.exe, rc.exe and mt.exe were all blocked by Cylance, once allowed everything worked again. Note that there are different versions of the build tools for x86 and x64 outputs and that all versions must be threated individually.